# How can i fit the equation?

Tags: equations, align, two-column

My article consists of two lines. Because this equation is so long, I wrote it so that it covers both columns. However, it still did not fit. (5) is overflowing. How can I solve this?

```latex
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cuted}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}

\begin{document}
        \begin{strip}
        \begin{multline}
        C(x,y,z,t) = \frac{m_T}{ (2\pi)^{3/2} \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z}\times\text{exp}\left(-\frac{(x - x_T - u_x t)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{2\sigma_y^2} \right)\times \left[ \text{exp}\left(-\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}\right) + \text{exp} \left( - \frac{(z + z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2} \right) \right].
        \label{atm_disp_lang}
    \end{multline}
    \end{strip}
    The advantage of this conversion  is to determine the dispersion parameters ($\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, $\sigma_z$) by using empirically derived models which depend on the distance between the TX and RX.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete minimal working example (MWE) beginning with a \documentclass{} and ending with \end{document}.

Comment: Comments: use `\exp` not `\text{exp}` (never use `\text` for that). You are using `multline, why arent you then adding any new lines to break the equation. It can easily be broken before the `\times` in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to make it span two columns, it isn't so big.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}
% \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
% \usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{stix}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{cite}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Last}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{The first section}

  \begin{multline}
    C(x,y,z,t)= \frac{m_T}{(2\pi)^{3/2} \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z}
                  \times{}\\
      \exp\biggl(
                                -\frac{(x - x_T - u_x t)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}
                         \biggr)\times{}\\
                \Biggl[
                 \exp\biggl(
                     -\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr) + \exp\biggl(
                     - \frac{(z + z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr)
               \Biggr].
               \label{atm_disp_lang}
  \end{multline}


The advantage of this conversion  is to determine the dispersion parameters ($\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, $\sigma_z$) by using empirically derived models which depend on the distance between the TX and RX.

\kant[1-4]\kant[5][1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

(Thanks to Celdor for the mwe)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `align` to split your equation, with the ampersand "&" indicating where the split point is and `\\` indicating line breaks. Note, in `align` left and right parts are right- and left-aligned, respectively. `\phantom{={}}` is only to add some extra space in front of the `\times` symbol.

```latex
  \begin{align}
    C(x,y,z,t) &= \frac{m_T}{(2\pi)^{3/2} \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z}
                  \times \exp{\biggl(
                                -\frac{(x - x_T - u_x t)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}
                         \biggr)} \notag \\
               &\phantom{={}}\;\times \Bigg[
                 \exp{\bigg(
                     {-}\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr)} + \exp{\biggl(
                     {-}\frac{(z + z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr)}
               \Bigg].
               \label{atm_disp_lang}
  \end{align}
```

[image]

You should also avoid auto scaling brackets and use their fixed alternatives, e.g. `\bigl(...\bigr)` or `\Biggl(...\Biggr)` etc.

---

Code example:

```latex
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}
% \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
% \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{stix}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{cite}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Last}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{The first section}
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \begin{align}
    C(x,y,z,t) &= \frac{m_T}{(2\pi)^{3/2} \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z}
                  \times \exp{\biggl(
                                -\frac{(x - x_T - u_x t)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}
                         \biggr)} \notag \\
               &\phantom{={}}\;\times \Bigg[
                 \exp{\bigg(
                     {-}\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr)} + \exp{\biggl(
                     {-}\frac{(z + z_T)^2}{2\sigma_z^2}
                 \biggr)}
               \Bigg].
               \label{atm_disp_lang}
  \end{align}
\end{figure*}

The advantage of this conversion  is to determine the dispersion parameters ($\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, $\sigma_z$) by using empirically derived models which depend on the distance between the TX and RX.

\kant[1-4]\kant[5][1-2]
\end{document}
```